# Elasticsearch: Can a Nested Object Have a _parent?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, each document can specify a [`_parent` document, creating a one-to-many relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html). Can the same relationship be created with nested documents?

It does not appear so. Below are commands that create an index, with a mapping that has a `_parent` defined for a nested property. After executing these commands, the mapping is successfully created, but the `_parent` relationship is not. Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/new_obj -d '{
  "new_obj" : {
    "properties" : {
      "my_prop" : { "type" : "string"},
      "my_nested_prop" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "_parent" : { "type" : "new_obj"},
        "properties" : {
          "amount" : { "type" : "integer" },
          "description" : { "type" : "string" }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: The `_parent` definition is not used with nested objects.  A nested object in Elasticsearch can't exist without a parent.  When you index your document, you index the parent doc and all nested docs in one shot.  Elasticsearch manages the relationship for you, and when you query using a [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html) you are querying for parent documents where nested attributes match the nested query criteria.

Comment: Yes, I understand that a nested object sits within another object. But it would be nice if that nested object could also reference a second different parent object.

Comment: Hmm.  Like comments nested on a post also relating to a comment-author parent-doc?  Nothing prevents you from including additional fields with information you could use as a foreign-key independently, but you won't get any relational-database magic out of Elasticsearch beyond the simple one-many hierarchical relationships supported by nested and parent/child.